# Android layout_rowWeight for API 14 or lower

Tags: android-layout

I'm trying to do something similar to this  using as less code.

[image: layout mockup]

I did this using `GridLayout`. But `layout_rowWeight` requires `API level 21` but I want to use `API level 14`.
How to do it at a lower API level or using another Layout?

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnSpan="3"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_rowWeight="3"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnSpan="3"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"

    android:clickable="false"
    android:text="New Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button24"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_row="3"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:text="New Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button27"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_row="3"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:text="New Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_row="4"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:text="New Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_row="3"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:text="New Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button28"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_row="4"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:text="New Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button29"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_row="4"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:text="New Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_row="5"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:text="New Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button15"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:text="New Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button18"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:text="New Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button30"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_row="5"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:text="New Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button34"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_row="5"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:text="New Button" />
```